# Is it possible to have multiple handlers with same category in jboss-7 logging?

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

I have defined two handlers for category with same name in standalone.xml file, like below

```
<logger category="ab.cd" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="DEBUG" />
            <handlers>
                <handler name="abDebug" />
            </handlers>
        </logger>
<logger category="ab.cd" use-parent-handlers="true">
                <level name="WARN" />
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="abWarning" />
                </handlers>
            </logger>
```

But i am getting exception when i try to run jboss 7

```
 14:28:08,090 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[143,4]
Message: JBAS014664: An element of this type named 'ab.cd' has already been declared
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.duplicateNamedElement(ParseUtils.java:235) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.parseLoggerElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.readElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingSubsystemParser.readElement(LoggingSubsystemParser.java:113)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:894) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

SO , i want to know is this possible to have two loggers with same category ? If not then how can I send data to two different handlers in this type of scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two loggers with the same category defined. How would the logger know which level it's supposed to use? You're best to use one logger with no level set and use the handlers to set the level you want to be logged.

Something like the following:

```xml
<file-handler name="abDebug" auto-flush="true">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="abDebug.log"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</file-handler>
<file-handler name="abWarning" auto-flush="true">
    <level name="WARN"/>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="abWarning.log"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</file-handler>

<logger category="ab.cd">
    <handlers>
        <handler name="abDebug" />
        <handler name="abWarning" />
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Parkins ... It worked without the use of use-parent-handlers .. i want to use two different values in use-parent-handlers for two types of handler.. how can i configure that ..

Comment: You can't. Only one logger can exist with the same category, which means you only get one configuration. Though really it shouldn't matter. If you don't want debug messages showing up in other handlers, change the level on the handler to INFO.